# How do compounding interest rates work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If you invest 1,000 USD in something that compounds at a 5% rate each month then shouldn't after one year you recieve 1,795.85 USD rather than 1,051.16 USD?

After each month shouldn't the value of the previous month go up by 5%?

My math teacher taught us the formula Initial(1+(r/n))^tn where as t is the time in years, n represents the amount of times it compounds in a year, and r represents the rate but why do you divide by n?

Comment: A yearly rate of $79.585\%$ would be a miracle !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your teacher is dividing it by n or 12 to change time in years. As the interest compounded monthly and formula used is for time in years.

Comment: Thank's that makes sense, I was mislead by the compounded monthly and didn't realize that the formula is based around years.